# How to trigger a function from onclick using Node.js

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, azure

I am new to using Azure, after using Google Apps Script to write web apps for many years. I needed to change how I was working die to some incompatibilities with iPhones. I was using javascript and HTML, so have recreated the app with node.js.

I am able to return the html page, and run client side scripts, however I need to be able to trigger a server side script so I am not opening up the SQL database on the client side.

The server.js script is as follows:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
  fs.createReadStream(path.resolve(__dirname, 'HTMLPage.html')) 
    .pipe(res);
}).listen(process.env.PORT || '3000'); // provide a default 


function processForm(form) {
  var firstName = form.firstName;
  var lastName = form.lastName;
console.log(firstName);
}
```

The HTMLPage contains the form code, and a button with an onsubmit command which triggers a client side script, however I can't seem to trigger the server side script (my attempt in bold). Can you please tell me where I am going wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<script>
function post() {
  var first = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
  var last = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
window.alert('Thanks, we will contact you soon.');

processForm(form).init; //This is the bit which is not calling the script

 };
</script>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />   
</head>

<body>
   <div id="formdiv">
       <form id="form" onsubmit="post();">
       <input type="firstName" class="form__input" id="firstName" name="firstName" />
       <label class="form__label" for="firstName"><span class="form__label-content">First Name</span></label>
       <input  type="lastName" class="form__input" id="lastName" name="lastName" />
       <label class="form__label" for="lastName"><span class="form__label-content">Last Name</span></label>                          
       <input  type="text" id="ddValues" name="ddValues" style="display:none" />
       <input  type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-block" onclick="post();">
       </form>
```

Instead of triggering the script, in the console I get this message:

Uncaught ReferenceError: processForm is not defined
    at post 
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Anyone know what I am missing here? Thanks

**EDIT**

Based on information from ruggierom & naga - elixir - jar here is the updated  script. My results now give me 3 undefined objects.

Server.js

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

  res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
  fs.createReadStream(path.resolve(__dirname, 'HTMLPage.html')) 
    .pipe(res);

  console.log(req.body);

}).listen(process.env.PORT || '3000'); // provide a default
```

HTML

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
   </head>
<body> 
<form id="form" name="form" method="post">
     <input type="firstName" class="form__input" id="firstName" name="firstName" />
    <input type="lastName" class="form__input" id="lastName" name="lastName" />                
    <input type="submit" name="submit"> 
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: I doubt you can directly call server codes. What is it that you want to achieve? like end result

Comment: I want to add the data from the form into an SQL database without opening up the database to people. I would definitely do it this way in Google Apps Script, so it must be possible.

Comment: Expose a `route` with `post` method. Within that route define your `db` connections and queries. Your form can `post` to that route with relevant data. Check out https://expressjs.com/